# Line segments or rectangles with hover information in R plotly figure

Tags: r, hover

I want to create an interactive figure of line segments or rectangles, such that each segment or rectangle gives different information when the user hovers his/her mouse over it.  I looked in the [htmlwidgets showcase](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_plotly.html), and I thought **plotly** looked promising.  (I am open to other R-related methods.)

Below is a simple example.  I can create a plot of the end points (t1 and t2) that provide hover information.  But I would like the hover information to appear any time the user hovers over the space between the two end points).

I can add a line segment using `add_trace()`, but I can't get the hover to work.  And if I add the second line segment, I get an error message:

```
Error in plot_ly(data = mydat, x = t2, y = y, mode = "markers", hoverinfo = "text",  : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

I can add rectangles using `layout()` , but again, I can't get the hover to work.

In the event that someone suggests a way to get the hover arguments to work for either approach, I would also welcome suggestions for how to code this for a large number of segments/rectangles (not just 2 as in this simple example).

Any suggestions?

```
mydat <- data.frame(t1=c(1, 3), t2=c(4, 5), y=c(1, 2), task=c("this", "that"))
library(plotly)

# attempt with one line segment - hover doesn't work
plot_ly(data=mydat, x=t2, y=y, mode="markers",
  hoverinfo="text", text=task) %>%
add_trace(data=mydat, x=t1, y=y, mode="markers",
  hoverinfo="text", text=task) %>%
add_trace(
  x=c(mydat$t1[1], mydat$t2[1]), y=c(mydat$y[1], mydat$y[1]), 
  mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text=mydat$task[1])

# attempt with both line segments - 
# Error in plot_ly, requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
plot_ly(data=mydat, x=t2, y=y, mode="markers",
  hoverinfo="text", text=task) %>%
add_trace(data=mydat, x=t1, y=y, mode="markers",
  hoverinfo="text", text=task) %>%
add_trace(
  x=c(mydat$t1[1], mydat$t2[1]), y=c(mydat$y[1], mydat$y[1]), 
  mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text=mydat$task[1]) %*%
add_trace(
  x=c(mydat$t1[2], mydat$t2[2]), y=c(mydat$y[2], mydat$y[2]), 
  mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text=mydat$task[2])

# attempt with rectangles - hover doesn't work
plot_ly(data=mydat, x=t2, y=y, mode="markers",
  hoverinfo="text", text=task) %>%
add_trace(data=mydat, x=t1, y=y, mode="markers",
  hoverinfo="text", text=task) %>%
layout(shapes=list(
  list(type="rect", x0=mydat$t1[1], x1=mydat$t2[1], xref="x",
    y0=mydat$y[1], y1=mydat$y[1]+0.1, yref="y",
    hoverinfo="text", text=mydat$task[1]),
  list(type="rect", x0=mydat$t1[2], x1=mydat$t2[2], xref="x",
    y0=mydat$y[2], y1=mydat$y[2]+0.1, yref="y",
    hoverinfo="text", text=mydat$task[2])
  ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `highcharter`, which wraps the Highcharts.js library.

```
# note i'm renaming y to x, since that's how highcharts will treat this dataset
mydat <- data.frame(t1=c(1, 3), t2=c(4, 5), x=c(1, 2), task=c("this", "that"))

library(highcharter)

highchart(hc_opts = list(
  chart = list(inverted = 'true')
  )) %>% 
  hc_add_series_df(data = mydat, type = 'columnrange',
                   group = task,
                   x = x, low = t1, high = t2)
```

[image]

Works just fine with no additional code required for a larger number of bars:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 20
largedat <- data.frame(t1 = runif(n, 1, 10), 
                       x = 1:n,
                       task = paste('series', 1:n))
largedat$t2 <- largedat$t1 + runif(n, 2, 5)

highchart(hc_opts = list(
  chart = list(inverted = 'true')
  )) %>% 
  hc_add_series_df(data = largedat, type = 'columnrange',
                   group = task,
                   x = x, low = t1, high = t2) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) # disable legend on this one
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can get hover information along a line by putting many points on the line.  You don't need to place markers at these points, so the plot will still look the same:

```
NP=100
mydat <- data.frame(t1=seq(1,3,len=NP), t2=seq(4,5,len=NP), y1=rep(1,NP),  y2=rep(2,NP))

plot_ly(data=mydat) %>%
  add_trace(x=t1, y=y1, mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text="hello") %>%
  add_trace(x=t2, y=y2, mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text="there")
```

[image]

Extending this to rectangles, we can do

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x=c(seq(1,3,len=NP), rep(3,NP), seq(3,1,len=NP), rep(1,NP)),
            y=c(rep(1,NP), seq(1,2,len=NP), rep(2,NP), seq(2,1,len=NP)),
            mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text="A sublime rectangle") %>%
  layout(hovermode = 'closest')
```

Or, if you want to label each side of the rectangle separately

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x=c(seq(1,3,len=NP), rep(3,NP), seq(3,1,len=NP), rep(1,NP)),
            y=c(rep(1,NP), seq(1,2,len=NP), rep(2,NP), seq(2,1,len=NP)),
            mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", 
            text=c(rep("bottom",NP),rep("right",NP),rep("top",NP),rep("left",NP))) %>%
  layout(hovermode = 'closest')
```

And for diagonal lines:

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x=seq(1,3,len=NP), y=seq(1,2,len=NP), mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text="diagonal") %>%
  layout(hovermode = 'closest')
```

In answer to your extra question "how to code this for a large number of segments/rectangles"? You don't specify how many is a "large number". But what I can say is that adding many separate traces in plotly can make it rather slow to process. Unbearably slow with a large number of traces.  The way around this is to add all your line segments in a single trace. For some effects (such as to control colours separately from groups and legend entries) it can be necessary to add NA values separating the segments and use the `connectgaps=FALSE` option in `add_trace` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38170340/2761575) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37924618/2761575)), but that is not necessary for this simple case. Here is a minimal example

```
line1 <- data.frame(x=seq(3.5,4.5,len=NP), y=rep(2.5,NP), text="hello")
line2 <- data.frame(x=seq(3,3.5,len=NP), y=seq(3,2.5,len=NP), text="mouth")
line3 <- data.frame(x=seq(4.5,5,len=NP), y=seq(2.5,3,len=NP), text="mouth")
line4 <- data.frame(x=rep(4,NP), y=seq(2.75,3.5,len=NP), text="nose")
rect1 <- data.frame(x=c(seq(2,6,len=NP), rep(6,NP), seq(6,2,len=NP), rep(2,NP)),
                    y=c(rep(2,NP), seq(2,4.5,len=NP), rep(4.5,NP), seq(4.5,2,len=NP)),
                    text="head")
rect2 <- data.frame(x=c(seq(2.5,3.5,len=NP), rep(3.5,NP), seq(3.5,2.5,len=NP), rep(2.5,NP)),
                    y=c(rep(3.5,NP), seq(3.5,4,len=NP), rep(4,NP), seq(4,3.5,len=NP)),
                    text="left eye")
rect3 <- data.frame(x=c(seq(4.5,5.5,len=NP), rep(5.5,NP), seq(5.5,4.5,len=NP), rep(4.5,NP)),
                    y=c(rep(3.5,NP), seq(3.5,4,len=NP), rep(4,NP), seq(4,3.5,len=NP)),
                    text="right eye")

trace_dat <- rbind(line1, line2, line3, line4, rect1, rect2, rect3)

plot_ly(data=trace_dat, x=x, y=y, mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text=text, group = text) %>%
  layout(hovermode = 'closest')
```

[image]

Comment: In 2020, two problems here: 1. Use `~` now for variables. E.g. `add_trace(x = ~t1)`. Second: this approach breaks down when zooming. See a demonstration [here](https://imgur.com/YGSdzZt). Also see an associated RStudio Community post [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotly-segment-tooltip/76672).

Comment: thx @julianstanley.  Have a look at [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400380/what-should-i-do-if-a-question-has-been-asked-and-answered-but-software-and-an?cb=1). If you have a new answer that works with a newer version of plotly, then feel free to add it as a new answer here. if you are looking for an updated answer and don't know how to fix it yourself, you could consider asking a new question and reference this one to show it is not a duplicate.