# Hover text over geom_segment in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

The code below creates a `plotly` figure of a line using `geom_segment` with hover text.

```
# Load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, y = 1, label = "Hover!")

# Create plot with hover
g <- ggplot(df) + geom_segment(aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax, 
                                   y = y, yend = y, text = label))
ggplotly(g, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

When I hover over either end point of the segment, the text appears as expected.

**My question:** How do I make the text appear when hovering over *any* part of the segment? I could create and plot a data frame with lots of points along the segment so that when I hover over the line I'll be also hovering over one of these points, but that's quite cludgy. Is there a better way?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, plotly's hover text appears only over specified data.  In this case, the line is not data - just a visual connecting two data points. The same things happens with geom_line plots

Comment: have you seen this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955568/line-segments-or-rectangles-with-hover-information-in-r-plotly-figure ?

Comment: @MLavoie I hadn't seen that – thanks for the link.