# Plotly add_segment() with tooltip along entire segment

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

This is a cross-post from RStudio Community [here in August](https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotly-segment-tooltip/76672) and [here in June](https://community.rstudio.com/t/tooltip-for-geom-segment-add-segments-in-plotly/69910). A couple of weeks ago, I also opened an [issue in r-plotly here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1832). I'm still not sure whether solving this problem requires additional `plotly` features, or if I'm missing something.

This is almost a duplicate of a [2016 SO post with a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955568/line-segments-or-rectangles-with-hover-information-in-r-plotly-figure/39028048?noredirect=1#comment112211323_39028048). This post is different because: (1) it requires using `plotly` (not `highcharter.js`), (2) it requires that a tooltip will appear on hover **anywhere** along a segment, e.g. not at just `n` points along the segment, and (3) minor syntax changes in r-plotly since 2016.

---

### Problem

In plotly, you can use add_segments() to add line segments between two points.

How can I show the user a tooltip when hovering over **anywhere** on the segment, not just either end? This seems like it should be feasible from a javascript perspective, but I can't seem to get it to work with plotly.

Example:

```r
library(plotly)
my_data <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 6), xend = c(5, 10),
  y = c(1, 2), yend = c(1, 2),
  text = c("First", "Second")
)

plot_ly(my_data, x = ~x, xend = ~xend, y = ~y, yend = ~yend, 
        text = ~text, hoverinfo = "text") %>%
  add_segments()
```

[See a gif demonstration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ7kN.jpg) (Didn't embed since it's a little annoying while reading text)

### Almost-solution

In the similar [2016 SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955568/line-segments-or-rectangles-with-hover-information-in-r-plotly-figure/39028048?noredirect=1#comment112211323_39028048), 'dww' provides a fantastic workaround by generating many points close together, and then using `add_trace`:

```
NP=100
mydat <- data.frame(t1=seq(1,3,len=NP), t2=seq(4,5,len=NP), y1=rep(1,NP),  y2=rep(2,NP))

plot_ly(data=mydat) %>%
  add_trace(x=~t1, y=~y1, mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text="hello") %>%
  add_trace(x=~t2, y=~y2, mode="lines", hoverinfo="text", text="there")
```

This solution is very helpful but doesn't answer this question because (1) once the user zooms past a certain point, they will no longer have access to the tooltip (see gif below), and (2) this solution is computationally-intensive--with hundreds of traces, I am unnecessarily generating thousands of unneeded points.

[gif demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuaJl.jpg)

### TL

Using the R port of `plotly` (or javascript), can I produce a segment (compatible with two continuous cartesian axes) that has its own tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the package author, this feature does not yet exist in r-plotly. See here: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1832#issuecomment-675721763